# Does the formula $\frac{1}{D + a} f = \frac{1}{a}\left(f - \frac{1}{D + a} f'\right)$ have a name?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, differential-operators

Using integration by parts, we can show that:
$$\frac{1}{D + a} f = \frac{1}{a}\left(f - \frac{1}{D + a} f'\right)$$

where $a$ is a real number, $D$ is differentiation, and $D+a$ is the corresponding linear differential operator. This formula is very helpful for computing $\frac{1}{D+a}$ applied to a polynomial, exponential, trigonometric or hyperbolic function.

For example, to solve

$$y' - 5y = x^7$$

rewrite it as $$(D-5)y = x^7$$ which is equivalent to $$y \in \frac{1}{D-5} x^7$$ which an be solved relatively painlessly using the above formula, which essentially manages your integration by parts for you and allows you to just focus on the algebra.

> **Question.** Is there a name for this formula?

Comment: Do you have a link with that formula Goblin ?

Comment: @Isham, no, I came up with it. But it's not very deep. Use the standard method of integrating factors to rewrite the DE $$y' + ay = P(x)$$ as $$y = e^{-ax} \int e^{ax} P(x) dx.$$ This means that $$\frac{1}{D+a}P(x) = e^{-ax} \int e^{ax} P(x) dx.$$ Now use integration by parts to derive the above formula.

Comment: I'm not sure one even needs integration to obtain it:
$$
af = af+f'-f'
$$
$$
af = (D+a)f-f'
$$
$$
\frac{a}{D+a} f = f - \frac{1}{D+a}f'
$$
$$
\frac{1}{D+a} f = \frac{1}{a} \left(f - \frac{1}{D+a}f'\right)
$$

Comment: I see thank you I know a close formula that gives the inverse operator of xV where v is any function

Comment: Oh that's nice  @rafa11111

Comment: @rafa11111, nice observation.

Comment: @Isham sounds interesting. Link?

Comment: Try looking up "D-operator method" you might find it. But I don't understand why this specific formula is helpful; are you gonna iterate it or something?

Comment: @T_M, well, it reduces the problem associated with $P$ to the problem associated with $P'$. If $P$ is a polynomial, you iterate it until the problem trivializes. If $P$ is something like $\sin$ whose $n$th derivative is a scalar multiple of the original function, you can apply the formula under question $n$ times and then rearrange the equation you get to obtain the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this sort of thinking is contained in conventional wisdom about $D$-operator methods.

You can basically write an infinite series for $1/(D+a)$, i.e.
$$
\frac{1}{D+a} = \tfrac{1}{a}(1+a^{-1}D)^{-1} = \frac{1}{a}\bigl(1 - a^{-1}D+ a^{-2}D^2 - a^{-3}D^3 +  \dots \bigr).
$$
Then when you hit this with a polynomial it obviously collapses to a finite sum. And you can imagine when you hit with an exponential, you can basically re-sum the resulting series to get another exponential. With this in mind, what you've written corresponds to the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+x}x
$$